# Are the photos I've taken with my iPhone gone?

Tags: iphone, itunes

I recently wiped my iPhone and much to my horror I realized I did so without grabbing the photos I've shot with the camera.

I've never explicitly gone into iPhoto to sync any images - only iTunes.  I sync regularly with iTunes and have backed up several times in the last few months.

1. Are the photos I've taken gone?
2. If not, where can I find them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up downloading iPhone Backup Extractor

http://supercrazyawesome.com/

Works like a charm.

Comment: For those who don't know, iPhone Backup Extractor lets you browse your synced iPhone/iPod Touch profile in your PC/Mac.

Comment: Glad to hear you've recovered your photos.

Answer (score 0):

If you've wiped the phone, then the photos are gone.  Know your pain on that one.  I normally go into iPhoto to back up pictures there when I take some to prevent things like this form happening.